# Error: conexión de SQL Server de confianza vs C#

Tags: c#, sql-server, visual-studio-2013, restful

Actualmente tengo el siguiente error:

```
"Error de inicio de sesión del usuario 'user'. El usuario no está asociado a una conexión de SQL Server de confianza."
```

Mi archivo de configuracion es el siguiente:

```
<appSettings>
    <add key="BaseDatos" value="Data Source=SRVBRD01\SQLEXPRESS;Initial Catalog=TESTDB;Persist Security Info=True;User ID=USER;Password=123456"/>
  </appSettings>
```

Que debo configurar para tener la conexión de confianza o una conexión correcta entre C# y SQL SERVER 2008 ?

Comment: Debes crear el usuario en la BD y asignarle los permisos correspondientes.  Tal vez SQL no admita conexiones con user SQL, o el usuario y contraseña no existan en ese server, o te estes queriendo conectar a otro server, ¿podrias validar la conexión directa en sql server management studio?

Answer (score 1):

Este error puede ocurrir por varios motivos. No obstante el caso más habitual es que le SQLServer está especificada la conexión para utilizar la autentificación integrada de Windows en lugar de la autentificación de SQLServer (por usuario y contraseña).

En la [página de soporte de microsoft](https://support.microsoft.com/es-es/help/889615/you-may-receive-a-not-associated-with-a-trusted-sql-server-connection-error-message-when-you-try-to-connect-to-sql-server-2000-or-sql-server-2005) podemos leer lo siguiente:

> Utilice un inicio de sesión válido de Windows para conectarse a SQL
>   Server. Si debe seguir utilizando un inicio de sesión de SQL Server,
>   puede cambiar el modo de autenticación de seguridad de SQL Server para
>   SQL Server y Windows. Para ello, siga estos pasos: Inicie el
>   Administrador corporativo. Expanda Servidores de Microsoft SQL Server
>   y, a continuación, expanda el Grupo de SQL Server. Haga clic en el
>   servidor que desee cambiar a autenticación de SQL Server y de Windows
>   y, a continuación, haga clic en Propiedades. En el cuadro de diálogo
>   Propiedades de SQL Server , haga clic en la ficha seguridad , haga
>   clic en SQL Server y Windowsy, a continuación, haga clic en Aceptar.
>   Cuando se le pida volver a iniciar el servicio SQL Server, haga clic
>   en Sí. Nota: Si utiliza SQL Server 2005, utilice SQL Server Management
>   Studio en lugar de Enterprise Manager para cambiar el modo de
>   autenticación de seguridad.

Comment: #frikinside, la configuración que refieres se encuentra activada.

Comment: @DAES Puedes confirmar que abriendo una conexión con el `SSMS` con esas mismas credenciales puedes autenticarte correctamente en esa misma instancia y en esa misma base de datos?